# "В()не закона" - слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

"В()не закона" - как прозвище.

Comment: Не очень понятно, что значит такое прозвище, но "вне закона" пишется так. 

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос не очень понятен. Слово "вне" пишется слитно. Вне закона, вне страны, вне космической станции.

А что такое "как прозвище"? Кого-то прозвали "Вне Закона"? Мне очень трудно представить подобное, но написание в этом случае будет определяться пишущим, так как написание имен собственных может не подчиняется общим правилам (за исключением специально для имен собственных оговоренных). Логичным, на мой взгляд, будет слитное написание всего прозвища: Петя Внезакона. Или в некоторых случаях: Джон "Внезакона" Браун.